# React JS : How to retrieve a string variable from a function using componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`enter code here`I want to retrieve a String variable (`profilesProject`) from a 'for' loop (`qualityPname`) within a `componentDidMount()` but it is not even going inside the function with the 'for' Loop.

The loop is working fine, concatenating the texts because I test in an export function.

Some clue what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import React from 'react';
import .... from ...

export default class MPApp extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    name: '',
    profilesProject: '',
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    findQG(this.props.project).then(
      (valuesReturnedByAPI) => {
        this.setState({
          name: valuesReturnedByAPI
        });
      }
    );
    qualityPname(project) {
      const numberQP = project.qp.length;
      var profilesProject = " ";
      if (numberQP > 0) {
        for (var k = 0; k < numberQP; k++) {
          profilesProject = project.qp[k].n + " (" + project.qp[k].l + ")  ";
          console.log(project.qp[k].n);
          console.log(project.qp[k].l);
        }
        console.log(profilesProject);
        return profilesProject; //String I want to retun 
      }
      return ("N/A"); //You should return something in that case also.
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="page page-limited">
        <table >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>QP: {this.state.profilesProject} </td> //here I want to bring the string
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>QG: {this.state.name} </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

ERROR IN DEV ENV  after ANSWER1 - Git bash

---

```
Failed to Compile

Error in ./src/main/js/components/MeasuresProjectApp.js
Syntax error: D:/Userfiles/Expression/plugin-example/src/main/js/components/MeasuresProjectApp.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (53:21)

  51 |
  52 |
> 53 | qualityPname(project){
     |                      ^
  54 |
  55 |                          const numberQP = project.qp.length;
  56 |                          console.log(numberOfQualityP);

 @ ./src/main/js/app-measures_project.js
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call `qualityPname` in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Hi Smanime, thank for your reply. Yes, that was my first way to do it, I created an Export Function...and produce the quality profiles string. but I couldn't bring it to the  componentDidMount(). I already have retrieved the "name" importing the function findQG(this.props.project) but it was a promise returned by an API. I couldn't do the same with just the String variable because keep asking me the promise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to return the value from the function, you want to set the state with the value. Try this:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        findQG(this.props.project).then(
          (valuesReturnedByAPI) => {
            this.setState({
              name: valuesReturnedByAPI
            });
          }
        );
        qualityPname(project) {
          const numberQP = project.qp.length;
          var profilesProject = " ";
          if (numberQP > 0) {
            for (var k = 0; k < numberQP; k++) {
              profilesProject = project.qp[k].n + " (" + project.qp[k].l + ")  ";
              console.log(project.qp[k].n);
              console.log(project.qp[k].l);
            }
            console.log(profilesProject);
            this.setState({ profilesProject })
          }
          this.setState({ profilesProject: 'N/A' })
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, Max, I made the change but  the dev environment is showing me an error at the beginning of the qualityPname(project)